How can I set my servlet as default mapping in Tomcat embedded?
I want to set my servlet as default handler at "/" in my Tomcat embedded project but it always return a 404 error on navigator. But if I set an index.html in webapp it can return and I can access to the servlet if I set the pattern to "/app" or something like that.
(I use tomcat 11.0 but I can go to tomcat 10.0 not below)
Here my class :
public class TomcatServer implements Server {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TomcatServer.class);

    private static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;
    private static final String DEFAULT_HOST = "localhost";
    private static final String DOC_BASE = ".";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONTEXT_PATH = "/";

    @Override
    public void run(HttpServlet servlet) throws Exception {
        ConfigurationProcess config = new ConfigurationProcess(this);

        Tomcat tomcat = tomcat(config, servlet);

        try {
            tomcat.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            LOGGER.error("{}", e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Application started with URL {}.",
                tomcat.getHost().getName() + ":" + tomcat.getConnector().getPort() + DEFAULT_CONTEXT_PATH);
        tomcat.getServer().await();

    }

    private int getPort(ConfigurationProcess config) {
        String port;
        if ((port = config.getProperty("port")) != null) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(port);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Invalid port number argument {}", port, e);
            }
        }

        LOGGER.info("No port specified; defaulting to port 8080");
        return DEFAULT_PORT;
    }

    private String getHostName(ConfigurationProcess config) {

        String hostName;

        if ((hostName = config.getProperty("hostname")) != null) {
            return hostName;
        }

        LOGGER.info("No host name specified; defaulting to 'localhost'");

        return DEFAULT_HOST;
    }

    private Tomcat tomcat(ConfigurationProcess config, HttpServlet servlet) {

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();

        tomcat.setHostname(getHostName(config));
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(DOC_BASE);
        tomcat.setPort(getPort(config));
        tomcat.getConnector();

        context(tomcat, config, servlet);

        tomcat.setBaseDir(new File("temp").getAbsolutePath());

        return tomcat;

    }

    private Context context(Tomcat tomcat, ConfigurationProcess config, HttpServlet servlet) {
        String contextPath = "";

        String webapp = new File("src/main/webapp").getAbsolutePath();

        Context context = tomcat.addWebapp(contextPath, webapp);

        context.setDocBase(webapp);
        context.setReloadable(true);

        tomcat.addServlet(contextPath, servlet.getClass().getName(), servlet);
        context.addServletMappingDecoded("/", servlet.getClass().getName());

        return context;
    }

}

I already tried to change the context path but still doesn't work, I tried to remove the mapping to "/" before to set it to my servlet still doesn't work. I expect when I call localhost:8080/ it return my servlet.
